# jquery focus not working after alert

Tags: php, jquery

I use the following code to submit a form and after submission, give an alert message to the user, clear the form and set focus to the first element in the form. However, the focus is not working and the cursor can't be seen anywhere. User has to click inside the input box after every submit. If I disable alert, then it works fine. Any solution?

```
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
    submitHandler: function() { 

     var usin=jQuery('#usin').val();
     var user=jQuery('#user').val();
     var ph= jQuery('#ph').val();
     var conductivity= jQuery('#conductivity').val();
     var hardness= jQuery('#hardness').val();
     var tds= jQuery('#tds').val();
     var turbidity= jQuery('#turbidity').val();
     var alkalinity= jQuery('#alkalinity').val();
     var chloride= jQuery('#chloride').val();

     jQuery.post("scripts/water_qual_add.php", {"usin":usin, "user":user, "ph":ph, "conductivity":conductivity, "hardness":hardness, "tds":tds, "turbidity":turbidity, "alkalinity":alkalinity, "chloride":chloride},  function(data) {  

     jQuery( '#eff_entry' ).each(function(){
            this.reset(); });
    alert(data);

     jQuery('#usin').focus();
     });


    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#eff_entry" ).focus(function() {
alert( "Handler for .focus() called." );
});
```

may be helps you .try it

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
setTimeout(function(){jQuery('#usin').focus();}, 1)
```

Comment: Actualy what is the reason for alert() ?

Comment: alert is used to inform user whether data updaion is success or failure. and reason for failure